# Cannot Pass State by React-native Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I try to pass State and SetState by using useContext.
But there someting strange: only one can pass to children compoenents.
I want to pass {isLogin, setIsLogin, name}, only name can show correctly like this:

also can run in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-shadow-m25slm?file=/src/App.js)

[codesandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASGlK.png)

```js
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

const AppContext = createContext();

const AppProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("molly");

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={(isLogin, setIsLogin, name)}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <Home />
    </AppProvider>
  );
};
const Home = () => {
  const storedEvents = useContext(AppContext);

  console.log("storedEvents", storedEvents);

  const login = () => {
    storedEvents.setIsLogin(true);
  };
  if (!storedEvents.isLogin) {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>{storedEvents}</Text>
        </View>
        <Button title="login" onPress={() => login()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>I am Login.</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple values as the JSON object, so your `AppProvider` should look something like this.

```
const AppProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("molly");

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{isLogin, name, setIsLogin}}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Notice the change `value={{isLogin, name, setIsLogin}}` instead of `value={(isLogin, name, setIsLogin)}`

---

There's another issue in the `Home` component which will give render error. You are trying to display `storedEvents` object which is not allowed. So change it to text string like `Not logged in` or something.

Comment: or maybe `JSON.stringify(storedEvents)`

Comment: vindev Thank you very much. I got it! 
@Shahriar Thank you too!